# Short Circuit a controller action with xhr for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller, short-circuiting

Is there a way to short-circuit an action with a method and ensure that other methods aren't called afterwards in Rails?

```
def update
   return head(:unauthorized) unless available_user_settings?
   if setting.update....
   ...
end
```

I would like to do something more like:

```
def update
   ensure_settings_modifiable!
   if setting.update....
   ...
end
```

But I don't know of a good way to render head and stop the rest of the action if the settings should not be updated.

Comment: Have you considered turning it into a `before_action` callback?

Comment: Derp, I guess I should have RTFM. "If a 'before' filter renders or redirects, the action will not run." -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: I guess I can make an explicit call to render, I'll take a look. Thanks Marc.

Comment: If you are calling `head` then you shouldn't need to make an explicit call to render.

Comment: @MarcRohloff Cool, if you want to put your comments in the form of an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `before_action` something like:

```
before_action :ensure_settings_modifiable!, only: [:update]

private

def ensure_settings_modifiable!
  head(:unauthorized) unless available_user_settings?
end
```

as the update action won't execute if `head` is called in a `before_action`

Comment: For anyone reading this: be careful because this before_action might run before others, so instance variables defined in those other before_actions might not be available yet. I just ran into that myself

Answer (score 0):

You could have:

```
def update
  # stop action if `false` is returned. Otherwise continue
  settings_modifiable? or return
  ...
end
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to put `head(:unauthorized) unless available_user_settings?` inside `ensure_settings_modifiable!` without the need for a return in the main action. I think this is doable with non-ajax b/c `redirect_to` will cut the line of execution in the controller. But I don't know about ajax responses.

Comment: @unflores: this doesn't stop you putting `head` into your method. Just be sure to also return `false` from it :-)